# Is this a valid proof of uncomputability of a function that doesn't use diagonalization?

Tags: computability, undecidability, proof-techniques

Let's take the function $f = \{(0,\pi)\}$.

If I want to prove that such function is uncomputable I can simply say that calculating $\pi$ from $0$ would necessarily require infinitely many steps, since a Turing Machine can only write a single digit to its tape in each step.

Is this argument well constructed enough to be considered a legit proof?
I think that this argument doesn't use diagonalization. Am I right?

Also: If I am right, can I apply that same argument to a similar function that has a periodic number in its codomain instead of $\pi$?

Comment: I changed "undecidability" with "uncomputability" in the title, but I'm not sure which one is better. Probably they are equivalent.

Comment: We usually talk about langauges being "decidable" and functions being "computable". Morally speaking, the two terms are equivalent but, since you are talking about a function, it's better to say "uncomputable".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct that you've not used diagonalization.

If you want to prove that something is or is not computable, you need a definition of computability. The standard definition is that a function $f$ from finite strings to finite strings is computable if there is a Turing machine $M$ such that, for every input $x$, $M$ halts with the value $f(x)$ written on its tape.

We already have a problem because the thing you're trying to prove uncomputable is of the wrong kind: it's not a function from finite strings to finite strings. As such, asking whether it's computable or not according to that definition just doesn't make sense – it's like asking if a cat is computable. In a sense, that completes your proof: you've shown that the object you're asking about doesn't meet one of the conditions for being computable, so it's uncomputable.

But it seems more likely that you have in mind some other definition of computability. What is that definition? Probably, if you try to write down that definition, you'll find that it doesn't make a lot of sense.  Writing out $\pi$ requires writing an infinite amount of data, as you've observed. To produce a definition, you're going to have to be careful because the very essence of "computable" is that a Turing machine does something *and then halts* and it's impossible to produce infinite output and halt.

The standard definition of [computability of real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) is, essentially, that a number is computable if there's a Turing machine that will output arbitrarily good approximations. For example, a Turing machine that computes the function mapping an integer $n$ to the string containing the first $n$ decimal digits of the number.  $\pi$ is computable in this sense: one way would be to use the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) that $\pi = 4(1-\tfrac13 + \tfrac15 - \tfrac17 + \tfrac19 - \cdots)$.

Numbers with periodic decimal expansions (i.e., rational numbers) are also computable in this sense. However, it would probably be better to consider rational numbers in the ordinary finite-string-to-finite-string model of computability, by representing a rational number as e.g. `1/7` rather than some infinite decimal expansion.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand the other answer. I was sure to have grasped the definition of computability, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Decidable (language) and computable (number/function) have a very precise meaning, review the definitions to see why your argument is false.

I'll just point out a few problems to get you started. First, if your talking about a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, then you should specify how it behaves on all inputs, not just zero. Since there's nothing special about your $f$, your'e basically asking whether $\pi$ is computable (again, a well defined term, which means it can be approximated up to any required precision).

Obviously, a Turing machine cant write $\pi$ on its tape in a finite number of steps. Requiring to actually write the entire number as output would result in a not very interesting definition of "computable", since as you said, any non rational number (or even periodic rational) would be "uncomputable". However, given $n$, you could write a program that would output (in finite time) a number $\tilde{\pi}$ such that $\left|\tilde{\pi}-\pi\right|\le\frac{1}{n}$, so $\pi$ is in fact computable.

Comment: Minor point: the function defined by the OP is a partial function whose domain is only $\{0\}$, and there's nothing wrong with that domain. So, I think the part "you should specify how it behaves on all inputs, not just zero" can be misleading to a student.

Comment: @chi Agreed. We can assume that the partial function is extended to a total function in some way, for example by having the Turing machine halt with a blank tape whenever the input isn't zero. On the other hand, this does hint at the fact that we need to define our notion of computability for whatever class of functions we're dealing with. (My example implicitly defined computability for partial functions in terms of extensions to total functions.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Be careful with that, though. There are recursive partial functions which admit no total recursive extension. IMO, if I had to prove $\{(n,m)\}$ recursive, I'd define a TM that halts on $n$ with output $m$, and diverge on all other inputs.